# Entity Framework - SportsStore - Book ASP.NET MVC 4 - Chapter7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

ASP.NET MVC4 - Chapter 7 (Apres/Adam Freeman) Page 175

Somebody did finish the example?

I am trying to do the example in the book, is the part under the section Preparing the Database.  The problem that I am facing is the View is not listing any products, my Table Products has some rows but the view is not showing anything.  Even I commented out the connection string and it don't shows any error.

My Product class (SportsStore.domain)

```
    namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string  Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ninject Factory

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory() {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {


            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();

        }
    }
}
```

Iproduct repository

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I too was on the struggle bus with this one, and with 2 days worth of searching on the web I came up with a work around that got everything to show up.

The book ask for you to add  a connectionstring in the Web.Config file on page 181, which replaces the default one.

`<connectionString>
<add name="EFDbContext"... />
</connectioString>`

The book is asking for a "Code First" method. I Couldn't get that to work so I went with a different approach by using the "Database First" method [explanation of the two methods](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access).

To do that you have to change the path to the database in the Web.config file from the previous one

```
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To this

```
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=YourDataBaseHere;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

You can get the Connection path by right clicking the DB you want and select properties, it will be the one labeled Connection String.

I hope this helps anyone else that is going through the book as well!

Answer (score 0):

I caused this problem myself on accident because I forgot to inherit from DbContext when creating the EFDbContext class.

Answer (score 0):

```
IProductRepository interface has IEnumerable<Product>Products{get;}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21555925)